# finding the most common value in sql and ordering by highest to lowest (asc)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple query.

```
    select id, patient_id, diagnosis from dbo.diabetes_rx_tracker

group by id, patient_id, diagnosis
```

the most common diagnosis codes need to appear at the top of the list with a count.

I tried using the count function.

but it returns all the values for each patient as 1 instead of adding.

```
select id, patient_id, count(diagnosis) from dbo.diabetes_rx_tracker

group by id, patient_id, diagnosis
```

I also kept throwing errors when editing my group by statement.

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The most common diagnosis codes per `id` per `patient`?, or the most common diagnosis codes ever?

Comment: per id is what i'm looking for, sorry to not elaborate.

Comment: And what RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL) and version are you using?. Also, you need all rows ordered by common diagnosis, or just id and patient_id?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like you're not aggregating enough. Each field in your GROUP by represents a field for aggregation in total with the others. So this will only show you the diagnoses by id, by patient, by diagnosis. Not very helpful.

To get the most common diagnoses period, remove id and patient_id from the grouping as well:

```
select
  count(diagnosis)
from dbo.diabetes_rx_tracker 
group by 
  diagnosis 
order by 
  count(diagnosis) desc
```

To get the most common codes across all ids, remove patient_id from the grouping and select:

```
select
  diagnosis, 
  id, 
  count(1) as CodeCount 
from dbo.diabetes_rx_tracker 
group by 
  diagnosis, 
  id 
order by 
  count(diagnosis) desc
```

UPDATE: Based on your new criteria, this is what you want.

```
select 
  id, 
  diagnosis, 
  ct 
from (
    select 
      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY count(diagnosis) desc ) as rn, 
      count(diagnosis) as ct, 
      diagnosis, 
      id
    from dbo.diabetes_rx_tracker 
    group by 
      id, 
      diagnosis
    ) ranked
where 
  rn = 1
order by
  CT desc
```

Comment: Your first select appears to be what i want but I'm not seeing the id and patient id attached to the count.. the second answer give me all the criteria again but the CodeCount is 1 for all.

Comment: You want the patient ids as well? So you want to see all the patients which have the most common diagnosis code for that id?

Comment: yes, that is correct... all the patient id's that have the most common dia code and count pertaining to that code.

Comment: if a particular dia code has 1000 patients associated with that code it should be at the top of the list and the ct should say 1000 followed by the next dia code that might have 850 patients associated with it.. it should be second. so on and so fourth... so close..

Comment: Okay, now you're confusing me - the final output should just be: ID, Most Common Diagnosis, Patient Count. Right?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, most of those are exactly what i needed. I'll use these to progress with my sql knowledge.. thanks again.